# how to purge debconf configuration for a specific package?

Tags: debian, debconf

I am using `debconf` to configure a deb package.  The problem now is that it does not raise the configuration while use `dpkg -i a2s_12-3456_amd64.deb` ('a2s' is the name of my package).

If I use `dpkg-reconfigure a2s` the configuration process is brought up, no problem.  I understand that it is because configuration values are already saved in debconf database.  I did some research and found a solution like this:

```
echo PURGE |debconf-communicate a2s
```

Which, of course, failed, i.e. the process finished with an "OK" output, but no effect at all.  Alternatively, I also tried to do `sudo apt purge a2s`, however, the debconf database still has configration keys of the 'a2s' package.

The file I am checking is: `/var/cache/debconf/config.dat`:

```
$ cat config.dat|grep a2s
Name: a2s/db_name
Template: a2s/db_name
Value: a2s
Owners: a2s
Name: a2s/db_serv
Template: a2s/db_serv
Owners: a2s
Name: a2s/db_user
Template: a2s/db_user
Owners: a2s
```

I might be wrong that this file could only be a "cache" of debconf database, i.e., obsoleted keys might still be there and are actully not used... That's ok, provided that if the package is installed "for the first time" the dpkg-configure interface should be popup automatically.

BTW, I am using **kubuntu 22.10**.  Thanks.

Moderator: This question is posted on serverfault.com, which I think might be more appropriate. Thanks.